# gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mrecord-mcount’

Tags: virtualbox, centos7

CentOS 7, kernel 5.12.8-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64, VirtualBox 6.1

I want to execute this command:

```
sudo /sbin/vboxconfig
```

but I get error:

```
vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
vboxdrv.sh: failed: Look at /var/log/vbox-setup.log to find out what went wrong.

There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run
  /sbin/vboxconfig
as root.  If your system is using EFI Secure Boot you may need to sign the
kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before you can load
them. Please see your Linux system's documentation for more information.
```

Here content of file **vbox-setup.log**

```
Building the main VirtualBox module.
Error building the module:
make V=1 CONFIG_MODULE_SIG= CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_ALL= -C /lib/modules/5.12.8-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64/build M=/tmp/vbox.0 SRCROOT=/tmp/vbox.0 -j12 modules
make[1]: warning: -jN forced in submake: disabling jobserver mode.
make -C /usr/src/kernels/5.12.8-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64 -f /usr/src/kernels/5.12.8-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64/Makefile modules
make -f ./scripts/Makefile.build obj=/tmp/vbox.0 \
single-build= \
need-builtin=1 need-modorder=1
  gcc -Wp,-MMD,/tmp/vbox.0/linux/.SUPDrv-linux.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/include -I./arch/x86/include -I./arch/x86/include/generated  -I./include -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -I./arch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I./include/uapi -I./include/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/compiler-version.h -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -include ./include/linux/compiler_types.h -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Werror=strict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fshort-wchar -fno-PIE -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Werror=implicit-int -Werror=return-type -Wno-format-security -std=gnu89 -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -m64 -falign-jumps=1 -falign-loops=1 -mno-80387 -mno-fp-ret-in-387 -mpreferred-stack-boundary=3 -mtune=generic -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mindirect-branch=thunk-extern -mindirect-branch-register -fno-jump-tables -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -O2 --param=allow-store-data-races=0 -Wframe-larger-than=2048 -fstack-protector-strong -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -g -pg -mrecord-mcount -mfentry -DCC_USING_FENTRY -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wvla -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-overflow -fno-stack-check -Werror=date-time -include /tmp/vbox.0/include/VBox/SUPDrvMangling.h -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-pie -Wno-declaration-after-statement -I./include -I/tmp/vbox.0/ -I/tmp/vbox.0/include -I/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DRT_WITHOUT_PRAGMA_ONCE -DRT_OS_LINUX -DIN_RING0 -DIN_RT_R0 -DIN_SUP_R0 -DVBOX -DRT_WITH_VBOX -DVBOX_WITH_HARDENING -DSUPDRV_WITH_RELEASE_LOGGER -DVBOX_WITHOUT_EFLAGS_AC_SET_IN_VBOXDRV -DIPRT_WITHOUT_EFLAGS_AC_PRESERVING -DVBOX_WITH_64_BITS_GUESTS -DCONFIG_VBOXDRV_AS_MISC -DRT_ARCH_AMD64  -DMODULE  -DKBUILD_BASENAME='"SUPDrv_linux"' -DKBUILD_MODNAME='"vboxdrv"' -D__KBUILD_MODNAME=kmod_vboxdrv -c -o /tmp/vbox.0/linux/SUPDrv-linux.o /tmp/vbox.0/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mrecord-mcount’
  gcc -Wp,-MMD,/tmp/vbox.0/.SUPDrv.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/include -I./arch/x86/include -I./arch/x86/include/generated  -I./include -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -I./arch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I./include/uapi -I./include/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/compiler-version.h -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -include ./include/linux/compiler_types.h -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Werror=strict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fshort-wchar -fno-PIE -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Werror=implicit-int -Werror=return-type -Wno-format-security -std=gnu89 -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -m64 -falign-jumps=1 -falign-loops=1 -mno-80387 -mno-fp-ret-in-387 -mpreferred-stack-boundary=3 -mtune=generic -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mindirect-branch=thunk-extern -mindirect-branch-register -fno-jump-tables -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -O2 --param=allow-store-data-races=0 -Wframe-larger-than=2048 -fstack-protector-strong -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -g -pg -mrecord-mcount -mfentry -DCC_USING_FENTRY -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wvla -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-overflow -fno-stack-check -Werror=date-time -include /tmp/vbox.0/include/VBox/SUPDrvMangling.h -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-pie -Wno-declaration-after-statement -I./include -I/tmp/vbox.0/ -I/tmp/vbox.0/include -I/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DRT_WITHOUT_PRAGMA_ONCE -DRT_OS_LINUX -DIN_RING0 -DIN_RT_R0 -DIN_SUP_R0 -DVBOX -DRT_WITH_VBOX -DVBOX_WITH_HARDENING -DSUPDRV_WITH_RELEASE_LOGGER -DVBOX_WITHOUT_EFLAGS_AC_SET_IN_VBOXDRV -DIPRT_WITHOUT_EFLAGS_AC_PRESERVING -DVBOX_WITH_64_BITS_GUESTS -DCONFIG_VBOXDRV_AS_MISC -DRT_ARCH_AMD64  -DMODULE  -DKBUILD_BASENAME='"SUPDrv"' -DKBUILD_MODNAME='"vboxdrv"' -D__KBUILD_MODNAME=kmod_vboxdrv -c -o /tmp/vbox.0/SUPDrv.o /tmp/vbox.0/SUPDrv.c
make[3]: *** [/tmp/vbox.0/linux/SUPDrv-linux.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mrecord-mcount’
make[3]: *** [/tmp/vbox.0/SUPDrv.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [/tmp/vbox.0] Error 2
make[1]: *** [__sub-make] Error 2
make: *** [vboxdrv] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

CentOS 7 is shipped with gcc `4.8.5` and newer ELrepo kernels need newer gcc to compile modules. So you need to install devtoolset.

```
# yum -y install centos-release-scl
# yum -y install devtoolset-9
```

After this, patch the `/usr/share/virtualbox/src/vboxhost/build_in_tmp` by adding the `devtoolset-9` env to the top of the file, either by copying contents of `/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/enable` or adding manually the following:

```
export INFOPATH=/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/share/info
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/lib64:/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/lib:/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/lib64/dyninst:/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/lib/dyninst:/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/lib64:/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/lib
export PATH=/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/puppetlabs/bin:/root/bin
export PCP_DIR=/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/lib64/pkgconfig
export SHLVL=4
export X_SCLS=devtoolset-9
```

After this, run:

```
# /sbin/vboxconfig
# systemctl enable --now vboxdrv
```

And you're done!